# Long text/string on Parse server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, parse-platform

I'm trying to save a long text/string on a parse-server instance that's hosted on heroku. I'm saving this through a node-js code. Of course, mongodb is used as the db.

The string is part of a parse object and when I try to save it, I get an error on Parse that doesn't help:

```
ParseError { code: 1, message: undefined }
```

Upon checking the logs through Parse Dashboard, I see:

```
Error generating response. { MongoError: Btree::insert: key too large to index, failing aaa.prod.$_p_productDescription_1 1034 { : "aaaLocation$jw5PnglCB1", : new Date(1494147063161), : "This is the text I'm trying to create in mongo blablablablalbalbalbalbalbalblablalbalalbalblablablalbalbalblalbalblab..." }
    at Function.MongoError.create (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
    at toError (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:139:22)
    at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:739:67
    at /app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:461:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'Btree::insert: key too large to index, failing aaa.prod.$_p_productDescription_1 1034 { : "aaaLocation$jw5PnglCB1", : new Date(1494147063161), : "This is the text I'm trying to create in mongo blablablablalbalbalbalbalbalblablalbalalbalblablablalbalbalblalbalblab..." }',
  driver: true,
  index: 0,
  code: 17280,
  errmsg: 'Btree::insert: key too large to index, failing
```

Is there no way to store long texts in mongo through a Parse server?

Maybe I'm not supposed to be doing this with such an implementation, but what's the alternative?

**Update**

The field that's giving me this error when I try to store a long string to it is called "productDescription". When I try to store the same long string to another field called "title", it works. Don't know why this is happening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out and some credit is given to Astro's answer. Mongo indexes queries automatically I had to delete the indexes that touches the "productDescription" field. The "title" field was able to store a really long text because it was never indexed by mongo.

Answer (score 0):

In mongodb, if you want to create an index on key then the size of key must be less than 1024 bytes.

Check this [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Index-Key-Limit) for more details and possible solutions.

Comment: Yup saw that. However, I need to use Parse server for what I'm doing. Also, I have another string field (called "title") in my Parse object and that field can store the long string. Why isn't the current field (called "productDescription") able to store it?

Comment: the size of field title can be less than 1024 bytes??

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you're saying. Basically the long string that I can't store in object.productDescription can somehow be stored in object.title instead.

Comment: It is possible that the size of title is less than 1024 bytes but that of productDescription>=1024 bytes

Comment: I'm storing the same string. Shouldn't the size be the same?